# SerializeJSON doesn't encode UTF8 characters in ColdFusion 9

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm having some issues with ColdFusion and JSON.  My users have filenames and other key words with characters like `ç` in them which is causing me a pain when I have to pass them back via JSON.

When I use the magic JSON command on my variable:

```
<cfcontent type="application/json"> 
<cfset variables.stGalleryItem = StructNew() />
<cfset variables.stGalleryItem["imagePath"] = siteRoot & '/images/350460/hellç.txt' />
<cfset variables.stGalleryItem["title"] = 'çççç'  />
<cfset variables.stGalleryItem["author"] = 'HI' />
<cfset variables.stGalleryItem["text"] = 'aa' />
<cfset ArrayAppend(variables.arrGallery,variables.stGalleryItem) />

<cfoutput>
  #Trim(SerializeJSON(variables.arrGallery))#
</cfoutput>
```

The character that gets spit out is �, which does no one any good.

Is there anything I can do to preserve my users' `ç`?

Comment: can you provide a more complete example? When I do `variables.arrGallery = "ç"` I am not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: is there another page that's calling this via an AJAX request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the Character Set in your CFCONTENT tag. I tried this code in Google Chrome without **charset** and it returned the text correctly. However, FireFox 3.6 returned the incorrect characters you listed.

This correctly returns the UTF-8 characters in Chrome, FireFox and MSIE:

```
<cfcontent type="application/json; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the conversion yourself : http://tojson.riaforge.org/ (native) or http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ (via a Java library)