# Escape special characters from JSON string

Tags: json, coldfusion, special-characters

I am returning a JSON string via AJAX call and then passing it to the browser, however, it breaks when there are special characters in the string.

Is there a function that can remove special characters from JSON string.

Here is my code:

```
var stdepartmentJSON = ajaxGetDepartment(ID);
var jsonDept = jQuery.parseJSON(stdepartmentJSON).replace();
```

I am using ColdFusion as the server side language. Tried using JSStringFormat(), but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you setting the content type for your page correctly?

Comment: Is this relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224899/coldfusion-9-serializejson-doesnt-encode-utf8-characters ?

Comment: I figured I can use a replace() on the JSON string, but since there are quite a few special characters for JSON, is there any regex that I can use in replace() function?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using SerializeJSON? [SerializeJSON CF Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79fa.html)

This should construct and escape data for you in proper JSON format. Sample usage:

```
<cfset responseList = structNew()>
<cfset resposneList["foo"] = "bar">
<cfset resposneList["wammy"] = "bar">
<cfset resposneList["escapeMe"] = '\ " /'>

<cfset jsonResponse = SerializeJSON(responseList)>
```

will create:

```
{"escapeMe":"\\ \" \/","wammy":"bar","foo":"bar"}
```

As a note, when using SerializeJSON, if you append elements to your struct with dot notation SerializeJSON will not retain your key casing. Example:

```
<cfset responseList = structNew()>
<cfset responseList.foo = "bar">
<cfset responseList.wammy = "bar">
<cfset responseList.escapeMe = '\ " /'>
```

will output:

```
{"ESCAPEME":"\\ \" \/","WAMMY":"bar","FOO":"bar"}
```