# Encoding issue with Japanese characters from ColdFusion's SerializeJSON

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

I'm working on a 1-page mini app that can be deployed on a client's site with 2 lines of code. This would be `theirpage.html`

```
<div id="builder_wrapper"></div>
<script src="http://example.com/js/loader.cfm?id=14"></script>
```

Then, on the `loader.cfm` page, it calls an all HTML file on the server and puts it into the "builder_wrapper" page:

```
<cffile action="read" file="c:\websites\example.com\wb-themes\#GetWBSettings.intThemeID#\builder.cfm" variable="html">
document.getElementById("builder_wrapper").innerHTML = <cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(html)#</cfoutput>;
```

So, I got a request to build a special theme in Japanese language. I replaced the English text  with Japanese code. But it is coming up as a bunch of random characters: ã¹ãã¼ã¯ ãã§ã¤ã¹

I added the utf-8 meta tag to my testing `theirpage.html`, and that didn't solve the problem. I looked at the server response for `loader.cfm`, and the characters are all ã¹ãã¼ã¯ ãã§ã¤ã¹. I checked the code on Notepad, and the Japanese characters are all there. So, I'm thinking the `serializeJSON()` is doing this.

I'm a little stuck.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6229141/1636917) to a similar question.

Comment: @Miguel-F, I tried putting <cfcontent type="application/json; charset=utf-8"> both at the beginning of the loader.cfm file and at the beginnning of the builder.cfm file. It didn't work

Comment: I'm confused by your description - "_I checked the code on notepad, and the Japanese characters are all there_". Where did you check the code in Notepad? Do you know at what point in the process the characters are getting changed?

Comment: I found the solution: The problem was was with the CFFILE read. It had to have a charset="UTF-8" property

Comment: @JackPilowsky pls offer your solution as an ANSWER to help the next person with the same issue (and so we know you don't need further help!). Cheers fella.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was not with the serializeJSON function as I first thought. The problem was the CFFile read.

```
<cffile action="read" file="c:\websites\example.com\wb-themes\#GetWBSettings.intThemeID#\builder.cfm" variable="html" charset="utf-8">
document.getElementById("builder_wrapper").innerHTML = <cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(html)#</cfoutput>;
```