# how to remove � in json string android?

Tags: android, json

Whenever I parse JSON string and display the output of json output in android Logcat, I always found

> "f������a������m������i������l������y������.������p������n������g"

in Logcat. The actual string is "family.png" but it displays as above. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Here is JSON data.

```
{"members": [
   {"user":"���d���e���8���8���f���5���c���7���3���7���1���4���7���6���6���f", "username":"���P���P���S���h���e���i���n", "avatar":"f������a������m������i������l������y������.������p������n������g"} 
    ]}
```

and generated JSON format is by Coldfusion.

```
{"members": [
<cfoutput query="getQry">
{"user":"#tuser#", "username":"#tusername#", "avatar":"#tpicture#"} <cfif currentrow LT getTrackQry.recordcount>,</cfif>
</cfoutput>
]}
```

Here is parse JSON object from URL.

```
public static JSONObject getFromUrl(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String content = null;
        JSONObject jArray = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        try{
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf8"),8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              content = sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jArray = new JSONObject(content);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }           

        return jArray;      
    }
```

Comment: Do you control the JSON data? Do you generate it yourself? Show use the code. Show us the JSON.

Comment: yap, I've generated JSON data by myself and added JSON data in my question.

Comment: @Pang I know. That's why I'm asking why "family.png" get wrong to "f������a������m������i������l������y������.������p������n������g" in android logcat.

Comment: @ppshein Ok we are close. Post the code you used to parse it.

Comment: How are you supposed to get `family.png` if you JSON data does not contain it (your JSON data contains `female.png` though)?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I've added about coding to parse JSON object from URL.

Comment: I suggest writing `content` to LogCat to see if the string is corrupted before or after converted to JSON.

Comment: @Pang as usual displaying "content" in Logcat.

Comment: So you're seeing `family.png` when you write the value of the variable `content` to LogCat?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224899/serializejson-doesnt-encode-utf8-characters-in-coldfusion-9

Comment: @Pang nope.. as usual.

Comment: `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf8"),8)` should be `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"))`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511880/how-to-parse-a-json-input-stream.

Comment: regarding @Hector comment, my json object is just like in my question. Please check question, sorry about that.

Comment: @ppshein Can you choose an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf8"),8)
```

### To:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"))
```

## References:

Please See the other SO question: [How to parse a JSON Input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511880/how-to-parse-a-json-input-stream).

Official docs for `public InputStreamReader(InputStream in, CharsetDecoder dec)` are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder)).

**UTF-8** charset information is also located [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using the incorrect charset.
Have you tried changing this line from:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf8"),8);
```

to

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I happened to be viewing my code here and noticed that the charset used is the culprit. was not looking at the comments. too many.